# How to compare the string of array elements with expected values using chai assertions

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, chai

I am looking for a solution to compare the string of array elements displayed are equal to expected values.
Basically I am reading data from dropdown and i want to compare the dropdown values with expected values.
Below is the code to display the drop down values:

await accountsettings.typeoffeedback.each((ele) => {

```
    if (ele != undefined) {



        ele.getText().then((text) => {


            console.log(text);

            }
```

Console result as:
Support

User experience

Performance

Enhancement

Other

I want to compare these results with ['Support','User experience', 'Performance','Enhancement','Other'] using chai assertions.

Appreciate your help team!

Comment: arre you using chai assert or expect ?

Comment: Hi @PDHide,I am trying to compare with expect.Aprreciate your help.

Comment: And which frame work ? are you using different framework than in build jasmine?

Comment: Hi @PDHide,I am using Protractor framework with cucumber and typescript.Sorry for late reply.